# Building OpenXML report in C# desktop app

Tags: c#, openxml

EDIT:  Report is OpenXML not HTML/CSS.  Title changed.

I have a desktop C# app that generates a word report using OpenXML from a template (.dotx).  I use this top level function right now to build the report from the template and save it off.

I have a couple problems:

1. When the `WordprocessingDocument` is saved (currently at the end of the using statement when it is being disposed) it creates a "FileIOError" exception on some computers.  The exception is with a temp file in the "Roaming/Appdata" folder.  The exception states that the file does not exist or does not have read/write privileges. The report is still generated just fine on all computers, but the exception worries me.  The computer accounts do not have admin rights, but only some of the systems produce the exception.  What is the best way to fix or begin trying to fix this exception?
2. In order to generate the TOC before anyone opens the document I have used Word Interop to open Word in the background, generate the TOC, and then save and close.  Is there any better way of doing this programmatically without having to use interop?

   ```
   public bool GenerateReport()
   {
       string source = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\XXXX.dotx";
       string reportDest = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\AAAA_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm") + ".docx";
       FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(reportDest);
       if (fInfo.Exists && IsFileinUse(fInfo))
       {
           return false;
       }

       File.Copy(source, reportDest, true);
       using (WordprocessingDocument package = WordprocessingDocument.Open(reportDest, true))
       {
           package.ChangeDocumentType(WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);

           package.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Append(
           new Paragraph(
               new ParagraphProperties(
                   new SectionProperties(
                       new PageSize() { Width = (UInt32Value)15840U, Height = (UInt32Value)12240U, Orient = PageOrientationValues.Landscape },
                       new PageMargin() { Top = 720, Bottom = 360, Left = 700, Right = 700, Header = (UInt32Value)450U, Footer = (UInt32Value)300U, Gutter = (UInt32Value)0U }))));

           BookmarkStart date = (from b in package.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<BookmarkStart>()
                                 where b.Name.ToString().StartsWith("Date", StringComparison.CurrentCulture)
                                 select b).FirstOrDefault();

           Paragraph paragraph = (Paragraph)date.Parent;

           paragraph.GetFirstChild<Run>().GetFirstChild<Text>().Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();

           CreatePidReports(package.MainDocumentPart);
       }

       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDocument;
       wordDocument = word.Documents.Open(reportDest);
       wordDocument.TablesOfContents[1].Update();
       wordDocument.Save();
       word.Quit();

       return true;
   }
   ```

Comment: I've seen this before, it's been a while, but I believe some of those PC are slower than others, you should wait and make sure everything you are doing has occurred before quitting.  It's most likely quitting the application before it finished.

Comment: Quitting what application?  The exception occurs before the I open Word.  The only other application to close is my own.

Comment: Disposing the object before `CreatePidReports` finished.

Comment: Hrmm.  Ok. It's all on one thread for one.  How would that happen?  Also, what would be the correct way to wait for it to finish?  I ask because since it's on one thread I don't see how it could NOT be finished before disposing the object.

Comment: Not sure, I don't know what `CreatePidReports` does, if it's not an async function then you would be correct.  WordprocessingDocument could be doing things async that we don't know about.  You could add a thread sleep for fun and test it on a machine that has the error.

Comment: I also noticed you are saving it in My Documents, some windows depending how the environment is set up might not like this.  It should be ok, but try running the program as an admin and see if the error persists.

Comment: Tried with admin, a 5 seconds sleep timer, and changing all files to be read/created in the base project folder.  Nothing worked so far.

Comment: What version of the OpenXML library are you using? Versions prior to 2.6 used isolated storage if memory usage got high which *might* be the cause of your problem. You could try upgrading to 2.6 if you're not already on it as it no longer uses IS. More details [here](http://ericwhite.com/blog/announcing-the-release-of-a-new-system-io-packaging-implementation/).

Comment: No.  Open XML SDK version is listed as 2.6.0.0 in project.